# Redirect to different pages based on which combination of checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

First, I've found a bunch of answers here that address individual aspects of my issue, but, for the life of me, I can't wrap my head around stitching them all together to function how I need them to.

Basically, I've got a single form with two groups of checkboxes -- the first containing 12 fruits (apples, oranges, kiwis, blueberries, etc) and the second containing 9 colors (red, yellow, blue, green, etc).

There are several combinations a user can create, but I'm only interested in whether a user selects 'apples' from the first group and/or 'red' or 'green' from the second group. There are three different landing pages that a user can reach based on their selections:

- Users that select 'apples' from the first group AND ALSO 'red' AND/OR
  'green' from the second group get redirected to page1a.html
- Users that select ANYTHING BUT 'apples' from the first group AND ALSO
  select 'red' AND/OR 'green' from the second group get redirected to
  page1b.html
- Users that select ANYTHING BUT 'apples' OR 'red' OR 'green' are
  redirected to page1c.html

I think I understand how to check to see if a single checkbox is checked:

```
var isChecked = $('input[name="apples"]:checked').length > 0;
```

I've given the 'apples,' 'red' and 'green' checkboxes unique classes and names so that I can target them:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="apples" name="apples" value="apples" />
<input type="checkbox" class="red" name="red" value="red" />
<input type="checkbox" class="green" name="green" value="green" />
etc.
```

I more or less know how to redirect the user to a location. What's beyond my capability is how to handle these combination scenarios.

Has anyone done something like this using js and care to share your knowledge? Thanks in advance!

----------- Added code/comments below on 2016-03-30 -------------

Here's what I'm putting in my `<head>`:

```
<script>
    function screenUsers(){
        var apples = $('input[name="apples"]');
        var red = $('input[name="red"]');
        var green = $('input[name="green"]');
        if ( apples.is(':checked') && ( red.is(':checked') || green.is(':checked') ) ) {
                // ... redirect to page
                window.location.href="http://www.google.com" ;
            } else if ( ! apples.is(':checked') && ( red.is(':checked') || green.is(':checked') ) ) {
                // ... redirect to page
                window.location.href="http://www.yahoo.com" ;
            } else {
                // ... redirect to page
                window.location.href="http://www.aol.com" ;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've tried using either `<input type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="screenUsers()">` for the submit button and `<form onsubmit="screenUsers()">` for the form tag, but neither triggers the script. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you got a button to submit or once changed you expect it to fire off? and also shouldnt these be a select dropdown not a input box if they are options?

Comment: Josh, there's a submit button allowing the user to make multiple selections before submitting their answer(s).

Comment: Roko, see code samples appended to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to apply your logic to your code - so here we go:

You said:

> Users that select 'apples' from the first group AND ALSO 'red' AND/OR
>   'green' from the second group get redirected to page1a.html

First, since you're going to access these a lot, let's assign them to some variables:

```
var apples = $('input[name="apples"]');
var red = $('input[name="red"]');
var green = $('input[name="green"]');
```

And, let's apply the logic:
    // If apples are selected, and EITHER red or green are selected...
    if ( apples.is(':checked') && ( red.is(':checked') || green.is(':checked') ) ) {
        // ... redirect to page1a.html
    }

And, you said:

> Users that select ANYTHING BUT 'apples' from the first group AND ALSO
>   select 'red' AND/OR 'green' from the second group get redirected to
>   page1b.html

So, some logic like so:

```
// If apples is NOT selected, AND red or green is selected
if ( ! apples.is(':checked') && ( red.is(':checked') || green.is(':checked') ) ) {
    // ... redirect to page1b.html
}
```

Lastly, you said:

> ```
> Users that select ANYTHING BUT 'apples' OR 'red' OR 'green' are redirected to page1c.html
> ```

This could / should probably just be handled in an "else" condition.

Glue them all up into a single script block:

```
var apples = $('input[name="apples"]');
var red = $('input[name="red"]');
var green = $('input[name="green"]');

if ( apples.is(':checked') && ( red.is(':checked') || green.is(':checked') ) ) {
    // ... redirect to page1a.html
} else if ( ! apples.is(':checked') && ( red.is(':checked') || green.is(':checked') ) ) {
    // ... redirect to page1b.html
} else {
    // ... redirect to page1c.html
}
```

There's certainly other ways to handle this, but this is the general pattern you can use.

Comment: That all does make sense. So, here's what I gather I'll need in my doc head: [edit - I guess I need to add an answer to include my code]

Comment: I've tried using either `<input type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="screenUsers()">` for the submit button and `<form onsubmit="screenUsers()">` for the form tag, but neither triggers the script. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes.  Since you are using jQuery, and it makes event binding easy, don't use inline events.  Instead, write this in your script block `$(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); screenUsers();});`

Comment: hi. i have the same issue. the first statement is working but the second is not working